# TypeError en iteración de psutil.process_iter()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando iterar los procesos con psutil para buscar un proceso en especifico y no funciona.
Subo la funcion completa de donde salta el error.

```
process_info = {}

 #Get processes with the name "aleatory"
    process = [p for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'aleatory' in p.info['name']]
    
    if process:
        process = process[0]
        pid = process.info['pid']
        print(f'{cfg.prefix} Aleatory found on PID: {pid}')
    else:
        input(f'Aleatory not found...\nPress enter to continue')
        quit()

#Get all command line arguments of process
        process = process.cmdline()
        for argument in process:
            if "--" in argument:
                mcprocess_info[argument.split("--")[1]] = process[process.index(argument) + 1]

        self.AleatoryPid = pid
        self.mPath = mcprocess_info["version"]

        print(f'    Username: {process_info["username"]}')
        print(f'    Version: {process_info["version"]}')
        print(f'    Path: {process_info["gameDir"]}')
```

El ERROR:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 213, in <module>
    sshare.Process()
  File "a.py", line 26, in Process
    process = [p for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'aleatory' in p.info['name']]
  File "astro.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    process = [p for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'aleatory' in p.info['name']]
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Buenas, intento ayudarte, necesito mas codigo. No me parece que el problea este alli. Con mi SO funciona sin problema.  Si puedes reportar version de python y paquete mejor, gracias!

Comment: Version de python 3.8.6, version de psutil 5.8.0. subo la funcion completa en la publicacion.

Comment: Quiero ayudarte, un TypeError es senzillo, pero no veo el problema. En mi SO no tengo ese error.  La linea 26 es exactamente la process = ... ?
Por otro lado el self. no es adecuado, se utiiltza en classes

Comment: Muchas gracias por intentarlo, creo que "localice el error" pero no se como solucionarlo, pero es interesante. cuando intento correr el programa con py en vez de python funciona, es curioso, el problema es que ejecutando py no me permite cargar librerías externas a la standart library. cualquier ayuda sirve. Gracias